# JQuery Sortable Lists - ConnectWith lists that require scrolling to get to them

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a series of [Unordered Lists with Sortable & ConnectWith](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) set so that I can drag LIs from any one list to any of the other lists. This works great. These lists all have a **containment** value added to match to a DIV that has:

> overflow-y: scroll;

As there can be quite a few ULs, we need to scroll down to see the ones not immediately viewable.

I am able to scroll the target DIV with my mouse however, when I try dragging one of the LIs from a UL where the target UL requires scrolling to access, the surrounding DIV does not scroll with the drag. I can see that the **containment** is working to some effect as I am unable to drag the item outside of the DIV, however it doesn't want to initiate the scroll when I drag.

I will see if I can get a fiddle together to recreate my issue - this is a small part of a pretty big project so will have to pick through the bits that dont work for me.

**EDIT**
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2sph4o58/38/) is a Fiddle with the problem. In doing this I have found out the cause of the problem. To get it working as I expect you simply need to remove the overflow-y: scroll; in the following CSS class:

```
.list-container {
  border: 2px solid red;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

to

```
.list-container {
  border: 2px solid red;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

My problem now is that I do really want that y-scroll on the container (or the UL itself - the same issue with both). Does anyone know how I can have my cake and eat it?

Comment: please provide some code here. something you have done so far

Comment: I am just working on fiddle to try and replicate the problem so will update when that is done. Thought I would get the question out there first in case anyone had any initial thoughts.

Comment: I have updated the question with a fiddle - I have found the cause but need a little help in actually getting what I want.

Comment: I realize my original question could have been more clear so have updated. Please let me know if it still makes no sense!